# Google/Apple account for corporate issued mobile phones

Tags: mobile, android, ios, byod

We are working on implementing MDM (Airwatch) for all corporate mobile devices (no BYOD will be allowed).

But I have a question as what is the best way to avoid users use their personal Gmail or Apple account to sing-in to the Play or iTunes?

I see that there is a possibility for employees to back up all phone information to their personal account and once they quit - they have all the data even if we wipe it remotely. 
We can probably create one corporate Gmail and register all phones with that but then they will need access to it to install apps or updates.
So I want to figure out what is the best way to limit their ability to manage the device and data on it for personal use.